# How to update supabase record?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, supabase, upsert

I want "item" to be unique so if a user click on the same item again, it'll update and add 1 to my "quantity" and add "price" and insert a new record if not unique. I tried using upsert/onConflict but there's not much information.

```
const incrementOrder = async ({item, quantity, price}) =>{
    const {data, error} = await supabase
    .from("ordereditems")
    .insert([{item, quantity, price}])

  }
```

Comment: Do you have a separate `items` table? In that case, you shouldn't copy the content of the `items` table in the `orders` (or `ordereditems`) table. Instead, you should just reference the item id, and hold quantity. The price can be dynamically calculated from the item and quantity.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on your Supabase project, go to your project tables, click on the column dropdown icon that you want to edit and then select 'Edit Column' (picture below):
[image]

If you then scroll down, you should see the ability to set that item to be unique

[image]

Hopefully that solved your issue. You should just be able to upsert and postgresql will enforce the uniqueness of the item column.

Comment: yes i know this but how do I write upsert in this situation? to update it if its unique

Comment: Either write `.upsert({ id, item, quantity, price })` or change your `item` property to be your primary key and simply call `update({ quantity: newQuantity }).eq('item', item)`